# Initialize STM32F pins using 2D array

Tags: c, microcontroller, stm32, stm32f4discovery

I'm working on a project that involves lighting a 7SEG display using an STM32F4 board, so far I managed to initialize all output pins using this code:

```
void init_library(vector_pin_t pines)
{

    GPIO_InitTypeDef puerto;
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOD, ENABLE); 

    puerto.GPIO_Pin   = 0xFFFF;     //Using only this to choose all pins
    puerto.GPIO_Mode  = GPIO_Mode_OUT;
    ...
    }
```

The above code works fine, but I'm wondering how can I do the same using a 2D array "v"

```
vector_pin_t v={{PortD,Pin_Port_0},{PortD,Pin_Port_1}{PortD,Pin_Port_2},
{PortD,Pin_Port_3} , {PortD,Pin_Port_4}, {PortD,Pin_Port_5}, {PortD,Pin_Port_6}, {PortD,Pin_Port_7}};

init_library(v);
```

Comment: Show the definition of `vector_pin_t`.  Does the definition of `vector_pin_t` change from your first code block to the next?  Or does `vector_pin_t` remain the same and you intend for `v` to be declared as an array, like `vector_pin_t v[] = {...}`?

Answer (score 1):

An easier way is to store the pin values for each digit in a single byte (1 bit for each pin).

For example like this:

```
#define NUM_DIGIT_VALUES 11

// Segments:
// ..a..
// f   b
// . g .
// e   c
// ..d.. dot

static const byte digits[NUM_DIGIT_VALUES] = {
    // dot-abcdefg
    0b01111110, // = 0
    0b00110000, // = 1
    0b01101101, // = 2
    0b01111001, // = 3
    0b00110011, // = 4
    0b01011011, // = 5
    0b01011111, // = 6
    0b01110000, // = 7
    0b01111111, // = 8
    0b01111011, // = 9
    0b01001001  // = overflow
};
```

You can then write the whole byte at once to a port.

For example: to display digit 2, write digits[2] to the desired port.

Comment: Hi! thanks for your answer, I already have the code you suggest but that's for showing the numbers, I have that part covered. The thing is that I would like to initialize each pin using the function init_library(vector_pin_t pines) giving it the 2-dimensional array "v" I wrote before in order to accordingly set every Pin from the array as output.